# iphone call forwarding info

Tags: iphone, call, forwarding

Is there any way to get the state of iphone's call forwarding info?
I just find in iOS5.0，there is a way to open "prefs:root=Phone",but it will be rejected by appStore.So i wonder is there other way to get this info?

Comment: Is there anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be happy to get that info as well.